# ASP.NET MVC application with windows and forms authentication at the same time

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, forms-authentication, windows-authentication

Is it actually possible to make an ASP.NET MVC application running on the IIS 10.0
to auhenticate users via `windows authentication` & `forms authentication` "at the same time"? What I want to achive is when the user enters application, it tries to log him with the windows credentials checking if he exists in the database etc. If this kind of login fails, he is redirected to the login view and is able to sign in "in a traditional way". `Windows authentication` should work only as the **intranet** login, and `forms authentication` to sign in from the **outside** (anywhere)... I'm still trying to understand if this makes any sense but I'm not really experienced with that kind of magic. Thanks for any response.

Comment: It's pretty difficult to do. I almost think you'd be better having two different sites. The one exposed externally can be configured for forms authentication, the internal one can be Windows. DNS would direct users to the appropriate site depending on whether they're inside or or outside the network.

Comment: @mason As I was reading quite a lot on this topic, the question is - will it work on the IIS Integrated mode ? Or I will have to completely separate two appliactions (for login)?